# Not able to click or page not responding to click in phantomjs-selenium in java

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am doing project on different crawlers and trying to mimic user actions. As part of it, I am crawling this [url](http://www.flipkart.com/moto-e4-plus-fine-gold-32-gb/p/itmevqynuz4fwxca). Here there is a zip code box and I am trying to click on it and extract text from the drop down which will appear after that. I wrote the below code but not sure why it is not working at all. Can anyone please help? I did exhaustive search to find root cause but got nothing. Any suggestions would be much much appreciated.

```
driver.getUrl(aboveUrl);
WebElement inputBox = driver.findElement(By.id("pincodeInputId"));
inputBox.click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.className("_3mWImx")).getText());
```

-- This gives null;
Awaiting help !

Comment: Actually there are more than one values in the drop down if you want to print all you have to used findElements(). Use this code it will give you desired result

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the node that you picked is the parent node of the element that has the text

[image: Dev Tools]

You should use

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.css("_3mWImx span")).getText());
```

And that would work. Also note that there are multiple element with the class `_3mWImx`, so this will only give you the first one. If you are interested in all of them, then you should be using `driver.findElements` and looping through the result

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are more than one values in the drop down if you want to print all you have to used `findElements()`. Use this code it will give you desired result :

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver( );
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/moto-e4-plus-fine-gold-32-gb/p/itmevqynuz4fwxca");
WebElement inputBox = driver.findElement(By.id("pincodeInputId"));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
inputBox.click();
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.className("_3mWImx"));
for(WebElement ele:elements)
{
System.out.println(ele.getText());   //It will print innertext of each element
}
```

Output :

```
From Saved Addresses

Loginto see your saved addresses
```

Comment: Use Phantomjs instead of firefoxdriver if u want